# Keyboard Shortcut for Changing Desktops in Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, workspaces, multiple-desktops

I know that I can change desktops by either clicking on their icon or rolling the mousewheel while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I'm wondering if there's a pure keyboard shortcut for switching between desktops.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> switches to previous desktop
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> switches to next desktop

Reference: [Lubuntu/Keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard)

In Lubuntu 16.04 LTS the following default shortcuts switch directly to a certain desktop:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> switches directly to desktop 1
- <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> switches directly to desktop 2
- and so on if you've added the number of desktops

Comment: One can also look at `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to see all the shortcuts available for keyboard and mouse.

Comment: To switch a window between the different desktops, right click it in the toolbar and select its "workspace" as they call it there.